# Entity Framework: Creating and inserting many to many relationships

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to the Entity Framework and am looking for some direction on creating the relationships between an entity and related many-to-many associative entities and inserting them in one operation.

The relevant entities in my EDMX:

**Participant**
ID
Name

**ParticipantCustomField**
ParticipantID
CustomFieldID
Value

**CustomField**
ID
Name

I need to insert a single `Participant` entity and many `ParticipantCustomField` entities.  The related `CustomField` entity will already be in the database at the time of insert.

I have a repository create method which accepts a `Participant` and a collection of `ParticipantCustomField` objects:

```
public Participant CreateParticipant(Participant participant, List<ParticipantCustomField> customFields)
{
    // need to establish relationship here

    entities.AddToParticipant(participant);
    entities.SaveChanges();
    return participant;
}
```

I have tried several methods but cannot figure out how to properly relate the collection of `ParticipantCustomField` objects with the new `Participant` before the insert.  I know the `CustomFieldID` foreign key as that is set outside of this method, but the `ParticipantID` foreign key cannot be set until the `Participant` is inserted.

I guess since this is the Entity Framework I shouldn't be focused on "foreign keys", which I think are only there because my associative table has a third column, but on relations.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set `ParticipantCustomField.ParticipantId`. The framework will do that for you. Instead you'd do something like:

```
foreach (var cf in customField)
{
    participant.CustomFields.Add(cf);
}
entities.AddToParticipant(participant);
entities.SaveChanges();
return participant;
```

I'm making some presumptions about your mappings here, but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track.  I was over complicating things.